# Добавление в список объекты разных тип

Tags: java, kotlin

Нужен список, который хранит объекты разных типов. Реализация следующим образом не работает:
(1)

```
var v = mutableListOf(1.0)
v.add(1)
```

Понимаю, что создается список типа `Double`,а если изначально создать список

```
var v = mutableListOf(1.0,1)
```

То все будет работать. Но как создать изменяемый список в (1) примере?

Comment: Если нет общих интерфейсов как в первом ответе, то используйте mutableListOf<Any>()

Answer (score 0):

Ищите общего предка или общий интерфейс.
В вашем примере это `Number`.

```
val v = mutableListOf<Number>(1.0)
v.add(1)
println(v) // [1.0, 1]
```